# Jekyll-build errored after 42ms - Gulp

Tags: gulp, jekyll

So i made a website before with a premade repository from github i think the author is shakyshane and i use the jekyll-gulp-sass-browsersync premade thing and the website that i made with this was working back then but now that i want to edit it, i just cannot edit it at all its very frustrating so if you guys could help me it would be really appreciated.

This is the error that i am getting

```
[00:22:54] 'jekyll-build' errored after 42 ms
[00:22:54] Error: 1
at formatError (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:169:10)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:195:15)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Gulp.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (C:\Users\Alex\Documents\jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync-master\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
at C:\Users\Alex\Documents\jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync-master\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
at finish (C:\Users\Alex\Documents\jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync-master\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
at ChildProcess.cb (C:\Users\Alex\Documents\jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync-master\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)

events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: assets\css\main.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: 2-modules/header
   Parent style sheet: C:/Users/Alex/Documents/jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync-master/assets/css/main.scss
    on line 1 of assets/css/main.scss
@import "2-modules/header";
^

at options.error (C:\Users\Alex\Documents\jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync-master\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:272:32)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having the same problem! Someone help please!